# Speech to Text - Map speaker label to corresponding transcript in JSON response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, speech-to-text

Every so often comes a piece of JSON data that presents a challenge that can take hours to extract desired information from. I have the below JSON response produced from a Speech To Text API engine.

It shows the transcript, utterance of each word with timestamps and speaker labels for each speaker `speaker 0` and `speaker 2` in the conversation.

```
   {
    "results": [
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "timestamps": [
                        [
                            "the",
                            6.18,
                            6.63
                        ],
                        [
                            "weather",
                            6.63,
                            6.95
                        ],
                        [
                            "is",
                            6.95,
                            7.53
                        ],
                        [
                            "sunny",
                            7.73,
                            8.11
                        ],
                        [
                            "it's",
                            8.21,
                            8.5
                        ],
                        [
                            "time",
                            8.5,
                            8.66
                        ],
                        [
                            "to",
                            8.66,
                            8.81
                        ],
                        [
                            "sip",
                            8.81,
                            8.99
                        ],
                        [
                            "in",
                            8.99,
                            9.02
                        ],
                        [
                            "some",
                            9.02,
                            9.25
                        ],
                        [
                            "cold",
                            9.25,
                            9.32
                        ],
                        [
                            "beer",
                            9.32,
                            9.68
                        ]
                    ],
                    "confidence": 0.812,
                    "transcript": "the weather is sunny it's time to sip in some cold beer "
                }
            ],
            "final": "True"
        },
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "timestamps": [
                        [
                            "sure",
                            10.52,
                            10.88
                        ],
                        [
                            "that",
                            10.92,
                            11.19
                        ],
                        [
                            "sounds",
                            11.68,
                            11.82
                        ],
                        [
                            "like",
                            11.82,
                            12.11
                        ],
                        [
                            "a",
                            12.32,
                            12.96
                        ],
                        [
                            "plan",
                            12.99,
                            13.8
                        ]
                    ],
                    "confidence": 0.829,
                    "transcript": "sure that sounds like a plan"
                }
            ],
            "final": "True"
        }
    ],
    "result_index":0,
    "speaker_labels": [
        {
            "from": 6.18,
            "to": 6.63,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.475,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 6.63,
            "to": 6.95,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.475,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 6.95,
            "to": 7.53,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.475,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 7.73,
            "to": 8.11,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.499,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 8.21,
            "to": 8.5,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 8.5,
            "to": 8.66,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 8.66,
            "to": 8.81,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 8.81,
            "to": 8.99,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 8.99,
            "to": 9.02,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 9.02,
            "to": 9.25,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 9.25,
            "to": 9.32,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 9.32,
            "to": 9.68,
            "speaker": 0,
            "confidence": 0.472,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 10.52,
            "to": 10.88,
            "speaker": 2,
            "confidence": 0.441,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 10.92,
            "to": 11.19,
            "speaker": 2,
            "confidence": 0.364,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 11.68,
            "to": 11.82,
            "speaker": 2,
            "confidence": 0.372,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 11.82,
            "to": 12.11,
            "speaker": 2,
            "confidence": 0.372,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 12.32,
            "to": 12.96,
            "speaker": 2,
            "confidence": 0.383,
            "final": "False"
        },
        {
            "from": 12.99,
            "to": 13.8,
            "speaker": 2,
            "confidence": 0.428,
            "final": "False"
        }
    ]
}
```

Forgive indentation issues(if any) but the JSON is valid and I've been trying to map each transcript with its corresponding speaker label.

**I want something like below.** The JSON above is about 20,000 lines and its a nightmare extracting the speaker label based on timestamps & word utterance and putting it together along with the `transcript`.

```
[
    {
        "transcript": "the weather is sunny it's time to sip in some cold beer ",
        "speaker" : 0
    },
    {
        "transcript": "sure that sounds like a plan",
        "speaker" : 2
    }

]
```

**What I've tried so far**:
The JSON data is stored in a file named `example.json`. I have been able to put each word and its corresponding timestamp and speaker label in a list of tuples(see output below):

```
import json
# with open('C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\example.json', 'r') as f:
    # data = json.load(f)

l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []

for i in data['results']:
    for j in i['alternatives'][0]['timestamps']:
        l1.append(j)

for m in data['speaker_labels']:
     l2.append(m)

for q in l1:
    for n in l2:
        if q[1]==n['from']:
            l3.append((q[0],n['speaker'], q[1], q[2]))
print(l3)
```

This gives the Output:

```
 [('the', 0, 6.18, 6.63),
 ('weather', 0, 6.63, 6.95),
 ('is', 0, 6.95, 7.53),
 ('sunny', 0, 7.73, 8.11),
 ("it's", 0, 8.21, 8.5),
 ('time', 0, 8.5, 8.66),
 ('to', 0, 8.66, 8.81),
 ('sip', 0, 8.81, 8.99),
 ('in', 0, 8.99, 9.02),
 ('some', 0, 9.02, 9.25),
 ('cold', 0, 9.25, 9.32),
 ('beer', 0, 9.32, 9.68),
 ('sure', 2, 10.52, 10.88),
 ('that', 2, 10.92, 11.19),
 ('sounds', 2, 11.68, 11.82),
 ('like', 2, 11.82, 12.11),
 ('a', 2, 12.32, 12.96),
 ('plan', 2, 12.99, 13.8)]
```

But now I am not sure how to associate words together based on timestamp comparison and "bucket" each set of words to form the transcript again with its speaker label.

I've also managed to get the transcripts in a list but now how do I extract the speaker label for each transcript from the above list. The speaker labels `speaker 0` and `speaker 2` are for each word unfortunately, I wish they would've been for each `transcript` instead.

```
for i in data['results']:
    l4.append(i['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

This gives the Output:

```
["the weather is sunny it's time to sip in some cold beer ",'sure that sounds like a plan']
```

I've tried to explain the problem as best as I can but I am open to any feedback and will make changes if necessary. Also, I am pretty sure there is a better way to solve this problem rather than make several lists, any help is much appreciated.

**For a larger dataset**, refer to the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KrnPXuFx). I hope this dataset can be helpful in bench-marking for performance. I can provide an even larger dataset as and when available or if required.

As I am dealing with large JSON data, performance is an important factor, similarly accurately achieving speaker isolation in overlapping transcriptions is another requirement.

Comment: would you kindly provide a past-and-run code for anyone wanting to help: make `data` a dictionary, skip the part about reading a json.

Comment: All the code that I've tried has already been added. I've commented the json reading part. The entire json is also available. The problem has been explained in full detail, I cannot remove anything as that would make it void and invalid.

Comment: something that one can paste and run on a local machine without editing, please

Comment: if you create a dict with `False` and `True` they will not be parsed unless converted to strings "False" and "True". My file is large and I don't want to make any changes. The json is valid and can easily be loaded into a json file for further file operations(read) and then to solve this problem. I don't think that's a pressing issue.

Comment: a bit more effort to make https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and courtsy to  people dealing with your question can be expected. time spend replicating your JSON locally could very well be spend on solving your question or actually other, better formulated question with runnable code. please refrain from judging _easily be loaded_  as this just ads slack/boilerplate burden on the people trying resolve your problem.

Comment: I've edited the json in the question, it can now be used directly. Please remove the `data` json from the answer.

Comment: I should have stopped seeing _I want something like below._ in question. Good luck with your project!

Comment: can you use pandas for this task?

Comment: Of course, use any library compatible with Python 3.6 . I do have pandas but if I don't have any particular lib, I can `pip install` it. I'm just looking for a solution as soon as possible.

Comment: k, posting solution soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using pandas, here's how I tackled it just now.

*assuming the data is stored in a dictionary called `data`*

```
import pandas as pd

labels = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data['speaker_labels'])

transcript_tstamps = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [t for r in data['results'] 
       for a in r['alternatives'] 
       for t in a['timestamps']], 
    columns=['word', 'from', 'to']
)
# this list comprehension more-efficiently de-nests the dictionary into
# records that can be used to create a DataFrame

df = labels.merge(transcript_tstamps)
# produces a dataframe of speakers to words based on timestamps from & to
# since I knew I wanted to merge on the from & to columns, 
# I named the columns thus when I created the transcript_tstamps data frame
# like this:
    confidence  final   from  speaker     to     word
0        0.475  False   6.18        0   6.63      the
1        0.475  False   6.63        0   6.95  weather
2        0.475  False   6.95        0   7.53       is
3        0.499  False   7.73        0   8.11    sunny
4        0.472  False   8.21        0   8.50     it's
5        0.472  False   8.50        0   8.66     time
6        0.472  False   8.66        0   8.81       to
7        0.472  False   8.81        0   8.99      sip
8        0.472  False   8.99        0   9.02       in
9        0.472  False   9.02        0   9.25     some
10       0.472  False   9.25        0   9.32     cold
11       0.472  False   9.32        0   9.68     beer
12       0.441  False  10.52        2  10.88     sure
13       0.364  False  10.92        2  11.19     that
14       0.372  False  11.68        2  11.82   sounds
15       0.372  False  11.82        2  12.11     like
16       0.383  False  12.32        2  12.96        a
17       0.428  False  12.99        2  13.80     plan
```

after the speaker & word data are joined, it is necessary to group successive words by the same speaker together to derive the current speaker. for instance, if the speaker array looked like [2,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0], we would need to group the first four `2` together, then the next three `0`, then the three `2` and then the remaining `0`.

sort the data by `['from', 'to']` and then set up a dummy variable for this called `current_speaker` like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(['from', 'to'])
df['current_speaker'] = (df.speaker.shift() != df.speaker).cumsum()
```

from here, group by the `current_speaker`, aggregate the words into a sentence & convert to json. There's a little additional renaming to fix the output json keys

```
transcripts = df.groupby('current_speaker').agg({
   'word': lambda x: ' '.join(x),
   'speaker': min
}).rename(columns={'word': 'transcript'})
transcripts[['speaker', 'transcript']].to_json(orient='records')
# produces the following output (indentation added by me for legibility):
'[{"speaker":0,
  "transcript":"the weather is sunny it\'s time to sip in some cold beer"},    
 {"speaker":2,
  "transcript":"sure that sounds like a plan"}]'
```

To add additional data around when the the transcript starts / ends, you can add the min/max of from/to to the groupby

```
transcripts = df.groupby('current_speaker').agg({
   'word': lambda x: ' '.join(x),
   'speaker': min,
   'from': min,
   'to': max
}).rename(columns={'word': 'transcript'})
```

*additionally, (though this doesn't apply to this example data set) you should perhaps pick the alternative with the highest confidence for each time slice.*

Comment: This looks like a promising solution. I will test it and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @user8212173,  see updated answer that also handles case where speakers are interleaved.

Comment: @user8212173, thanks, i tested, and it seems to be working fine, meaning properly associating speaker with transcript, and also maintaining the order of transcript. on a short sample that you shared, its pretty quick. you tell us if its efficient enough. there may not be too much more to optimize from this point onward. Also, I tested the other answer, and it fails to segment dialogue properly

Comment: @HaleemurAli it fails to segment dialogue because it's not written to segment dialogue because that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: +1 for a Pandas solution. I just tested this solution on my data-set and I get clear isolation of speakers with their corresponding transcripts and the performance is also quite impressive. I am new to pandas but this has led me to believe that I must explore this amazing library. Personally, I like list comprehensions for their speed and compactness, but as you mentioned in the beginning that I should not be using this in production code, do you have any other suggestions? Meanwhile, I will test this code against a few larger data-sets and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @user8212173 list comprehensions are elegant, but nesting can make it difficult to read, you could use nested for-loops instead, however, for interactive development in console, i can evaluate a comprehension, see results, press up and modify to add more nesting or other conditions. `sum(<list>, [])` is quick to type in the console, thus good for quick prototyping but inefficient, and also may confuse those who don't know how the reduction works. use a for loop here and append the extracted nested elements to a final flattened list

Comment: @user8212173, after writing the above comment, I went back and optimized the list comprehension used to create `transcript_tstamps`. the newer version is both more elegant (IMO) and definitely faster.

Comment: This solution works very well for large datasets and serves my purpose. Answer accepted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tried using JS
See if this works for you in the similar way using python

```
var resultTimestampLen = 0;

arrLen = JSON.parse(sTot_resuts.results.length);
for(var i = 0; i<arrLen; i++){

    speakerLablefrom = sTot_resuts.speaker_labels[resultTimestampLen].from;

    speakerLabelto = sTot_resuts.speaker_labels[resultTimestampLen].to;

    speakerId = sTot_resuts.speaker_labels[resultTimestampLen].speaker;


    var findSpeaker = new Array();
    findSpeaker = sTot_resuts.results[i].alternatives[0].timestamps[0];

    var timeStampFrom = findSpeaker[1];

    var timeStampto = findSpeaker[2];


      if(timeStampFrom === speakerLablefrom && timeStampto === speakerLabelto){
        console.log('Speaker '+sTot_resuts.speaker_labels[resultTimestampLen].speaker + ' ' + sTot_resuts.results[i].alternatives[0].transcript);
        var resultsTimestamp = new Array();
        resultsTimestamp = sTot_resuts.results[i].alternatives[0].timestamps.length;

        resultTimestampLen = resultsTimestamp+resultTimestampLen;
      }else{
        console.log('resultTimestampLen '+resultTimestampLen + 'speakerLablefrom '+speakerLablefrom + 'speakerLabelto '+speakerLabelto + 'timeStampFrom '+timeStampFrom + 'timeStampto '+timeStampto);
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it by throwing words into a dict based on their timestamp, and them matching them to their speakers:

```
times = {}
for r in data['results']:
    for word in r['alternatives'][0]['timestamps']:
        times[(word[1], word[2])] = word[0]

transcripts = {}
for r in data['speaker_labels']:
    speaker = r['speaker']
    if speaker in transcripts:
        transcripts[speaker].append(times[(r['from'], r['to'])])
    else:
        transcripts[speaker] = [times[(r['from'], r['to'])]]

print([{'speaker': k, 'transcript': ' '.join(transcripts[k])} for k in transcripts])
```

It runs on the example provided 1,000,000 times in ~12.34 seconds, so hopefully it's fast enough for what you want.

Comment: And FWIW, the pandas solution has taken from about 30 seconds before I started writing this until............. will update. However, it's possible (almost definite) that the pandas answer just has a lot of overhead that doesn't lend itself to being run 1,000,000 times well. Mind linking us to a pastebin of a larger json example for testing?

Comment: @user8212173, a larger dataset would let solvers create less buggy solutions and also test for efficiency. that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answers, I am still testing on my own dataset and of course, performance is an important factor. I will soon share a larger dataset for testing.

Comment: I've added a pastebin with larger  data-set for performance bench-marking.

Comment: Thanks. Do you need speakers separated when they alternate or is one string transcript enough for each?

Comment: The transcript is formed on words spoken at certain timestamps. So the output should also be formed based on the timing of the spoken word. It does not matter if `speaker 0` spoke consecutively or alternately, what matters is the timing. The transcript and speaker must be in one single json object nested inside the larger json result(as shown in the question).

Comment: Okay. I think this does what you want, and it is pretty fast.

Comment: I tested this code on my JSON data and all I get is two speaker labels with all their transcription in one key-value pair each. Not the right solution. All I'm looking for is which speaker spoke what.

Comment: I thought it didn't matter if they spoke consecutively or alternately? Do you need them split up by what sentence they speak?